# How to split the list of list in to seperate column

Tags: pandas

My df is below

```
gender    list
MALE    [['Office/Work'],  ['31-40'], ['Salaried'], ['Master’s/PhD degree']]
```

Expected Out  df['out']

```
Type         Age       EmpType       Education
Office/Work  31-40    Salaried       Master’s/PhD degree
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only one element values in lists use:

```
c = ['Type','Age','EmpType','Education']
df = pd.DataFrame([[y[0] for y in x] for x in df['list']], columns=c)
print (df)
          Type    Age   EmpType           Education
0  Office/Work  31-40  Salaried  Masters/PhD degree
```

Comment: if there are multiple element values then how to do?

Comment: @Maws - Can you change data sample? Do you think for each value separate column like `df = pd.DataFrame([[z for y in x for z in y] for x in df['list']])` ?

Comment: for me its splitting with letter not with [list]

Comment: `f = pd.DataFrame([[z for z in x] for x in df['final_resp']])`  same out

Comment: @Maws possible change sample data? Or problem is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'list']))` is not list, but string?

Comment: @Maws - it should return list ot str - `print (type(df.loc[0, 'list']))`

Comment: @Maws - If not working, try `print (type(df['list'].iat[0]))`

Comment: <class 'str'>  its string only

Comment: @Maws - OK, so try `import ast` and `df['list'] = df['list'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my solution